# Return XML when consuming a secure web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, workday-api

I am currently trying to consume a generated report as a webservice to integrate some data into our system.  Because the service itself is generated, the response can change frequently as things are added to it.  While the endpoint and response may change, the request body will always be the same (taken from soapui):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Execute_Report>
      </Execute_Report>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the above request for any endpoint (different reports) and allow for changes in the response.  Ideally, I want to just return the raw XML of the response as I can allow for change easier with how I handle the XML if I'm not being tied to a data contract.

It is also worth noting that the service uses WS-Security and a Username/Password is passed as part of the request.

I've used WCF and the files generated from svcutil work great when I don't expect the service to change frequently. However because these webservices are generated change is expected, and if I can get away from it, I don't want to be at the mercy of re-generating a new file with svcutil whenever things change, or have to generate a file (and maintain) for all the different generated webservices.

At the end of the day the question is: ***How do I consume a webservice and return the raw XML while still being able to apply WS-Security to the request?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept searching around and found this answer:

[.NET client authentication and SOAP credential headers for a CXF web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263640/net-client-authentication-and-soap-credential-headers-for-a-cxf-web-service)

This allowed me to do what I was after.